# 'Un-select' a radiobutton?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I have always wondered if there is any way or trick to un-select a radio button once you have selected one.

I'm asking this as a generic question, not regarding a specific program. it could be a desktop program or a webpage.

Once you click on a radio button it seems like there is no way to unselect it, so if you wanted to leave the field blank, you can't once you have already made a selection. It kind of 'forces' you to select something.

<sub>**UPDATE**: Im sorry, I was referring to radio buttons and not checkboxes, I confused the terms.</sub>

Comment: Can you give a specific example of where you have seen this behavior?  Typically check boxes allow you to both check and uncheck the box.

Comment: I think you're talking about radio buttons?

Comment: @fretje: yes, im sorry. i was referring to radio buttons

Comment: radiobuttons can't be de-selected "by design"

Comment: If you've ever encountered an old car radio, the preset buttons were physical objects that you had to push in. Pushing in one popped out the other. It was nigh-impossible to "unselect" one without pushing in another. I'm sure that's where the name "radio buttons" comes from.

Comment: @Al Everett; +1 but I remember the 'press-to-at-a-time' trick which released all the buttons... at least on my old radios.

Comment: @Al Everett, on my radio, I can press any button halfway to release all buttons. Still have one at home.

Answer (score 31):

You're thinking of radio buttons:

[image: a group of round checkboxes where only one can be selected at a time]

…and any interface that leaves you wanting to uncheck a group of radio buttons is Doing it Wrong™. Radio buttons should (best) start out with a default option checked, not accept input if the user doesn't make a choice, or (worst) provide a button to uncheck everything.

If complaining to the software/website designer isn't an option, here's a bookmarklet which unchecks every radio button on a page:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20inputs%20=%20document.getElementsByTagName(%27input%27);for(var%20i%20=%20inputs.length-1;i>=0;i--){if(inputs[i].getAttribute(%27type%27)===%27radio%27)inputs[i].checked=false}})()
```

...and here's a version that works in the console:

```
(function(){var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');for(var i = inputs.length-1;i>=0;i--){if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type')==='radio')inputs[i].checked=false}})()
```

If you're dealing with desktop software, the only option is usually to exit out of the problematic screen and go back in.

Comment: I stumble upon this every now and again with online surveys that are badly designed. I couldn't run this script as it said "_Unexpected token %_" when running it in Chrome's console. What I did instead was use Chrome's ability to edit html: Press F12. Press the little magnifying glass on the far left, select the radiobutton (it should be an `li` element), then right click the surrounding `ul` element and select **Edit as HTML**. Copy one of the other radio buttons (`li` elements) and insert it beside the others. Select it on the page, and then edit the `ul` again to remove the radio button.

Comment: @AskeB. I just added a version that works in the console!

Answer (score 7):

Add a radio button called None

Comment: +1 That's what I would do... Radio buttons can't be de-selected "by design"!

Answer (score 3):

That is generally a problem with Radio Buttons, the circular type of selection widgets that allow for only one of a group to be selected.  Checkboxes are designed to have them either checked or unchecked.  I doubt that checkboxes in general don't allow deselection.  It might be good to give examples of your issue.

Note that if you have a problem 'unselecting' the last selected item in a set, it is always good to attempt clicking on your selection  while pressing CTRL at the same time.

Comment: It's not really a problem, they're supposed to require a selection.  They aren't supposed to be used when "no answer" is valid.

Comment: I was using 'generally a problem with' to as a rhetorical device to point out that the OP was probably referring to radio buttons, not checkboxes.  I didn't mean to imply that it actually was a problem.

Comment: +1 for the CTRL solution, which is often not known

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If it's a radio button you could use [this Javascript sample](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/7199) or perhaps do something with AutoHotKey to make your own shortcut for it:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function unCheckRadio(oRadio) {
      var or = document.getElementsByName(oRadio);
      for (var i = 0; i < or.length; i++) {
         or[i].checked = false;
     }
}
//-->
</script>
```

---

Not really relevant anymore, though still useful:

> I have written a couple of posts on
>   the topic keyboard Shortcuts for
>   different application and How to
>   improve efficiency and experience by
>   learning to use keyboard shortcuts.
>   But whenever I login to any account, I
>   use the tab button to move across
>   field box to enter the userid and
>   password and I use the mouse to select
>   or deselect ‘Keep me signed in’ check
>   box.
>
> [image]
>
> Only today I realized that I am not
>   aware what's the keyboard shortcut
>   to select or deselect the check box.
>   Did a bit of Googling and found out
>   that **Space bar** is used for check box.
>   You may come across check box in
>   various places like ‘Remember Me’ or
>   ‘I accept the policy’ and in all those
>   places do remember to use the space
>   bar to select or deselect a check box.

Comment: Note Firefox Keyboard guide mentions that a radio button doesn't have a toggle (on/off) option

Comment: Well this isn't really useful anymore after he edited his question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not referring to a radio button? You can usually uncheck a checkbox.
If you are referring to a radio button, the closest thing I can think of is using the dev toolbar plugin for Firefox's to clear radio buttons.
Menu > Forms > Clear Radio buttons

Comment: yes, im sorry, i was referring to radio buttons.